# One or two tables centered in a div

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to display divs with either one or two tables next to each other. The tables should be centered:

```
*div****************************************************************************
*                                      Table 1                                 *
*                                   |...|...|...|                              *
********************************************************************************
*div****************************************************************************
*                    Table 2                             Table 3               *
*                 |...|...|...|                       |...|...|...|            *
********************************************************************************
```

My html looks something like this:

```
<div class="all">
  <div class="row"> <!-- row with 1 table in it -->
    <div class="column">
      <table class="centered">
          ...
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row"> <!-- row with 2 tables in it -->
    <div class="column">
      <table class="centered">
          ...
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <table class="centered">
          ...
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have so far failed to find the proper CSS for it. My current CSS looks like this:

```
div.row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

div.column {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table.centered {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

jsfiddle is here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9w7yt0f/)

Please help me understand CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flexbox and it will work no matter how columns you add in each row:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r9mnLgLw/3/)

Comment: sorry, but that fiddle shows all three tables below each other (?)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use flexbox (not compatible to older browsers), erase the `display: inline;` from `column`, add `text-align: center;` to it and also add `display: inline-table;` to `.centered`:

(inline elements can be centered using `text-align: center;`  on their container)

```css
div.row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

div.column {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

table.centered {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <table class="centered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <table class="centered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table class="centered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pLccg6w3/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for but here is a fiddle I posted. I made table.centered `float:left;` and then added a .left and . right class for the first and third box and simply gave them a `margin-top:100px;`

https://jsfiddle.net/k9w7yt0f/1/

Comment: no, that's not what I wanted. I don't want table 1 and table 3 moved down. I want table 1 in the first div over the div with table 2 and table 3. I edited my question to show this better.